# Error in code, "illegal start of expression"

Tags: java

I am making this game for a class, using BlueJ, and I have no idea what is wrong with this code.

I have tried changing the public static void at the bottom to a private and I even removed the if and else if statements to see if it would make any change but it didn't really accomplish anything.

By the way, the huge words in ASCII are for the game that I am making.

```````
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Input
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner name is scanny fyi

        System.out.print("Press Enter to begin game"); //first message!

        String EnterPress = scanny.nextLine(); //varible for when you press enter

        System.out.println(" \n\n");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("        ./osyhhhhhhhhyso/-                                                                                                                                                                                .yyyyyyy.");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("     `/yhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy/`                                                                                                                                                                             .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("    .yhhhhhhhhhyyyyhhhhhhhhhy.                                                                                                                                                                            .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("   .hhhhhhhh+-``````./yhhhhhhh.                                                                                                                                                                           .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("   yhhhhhhy.          `shhhhhhs                                                                                                                                                                           .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  :hhhhhhh-            .hhhhhhh.                                                                                                                                                                          .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  ohhhhhhh              yhhhhhh/                                                                                                                                                                          .hhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  yhhhhhhy              shhhhhh+                      ```             ``.```                                                 ``.``                      ``..``                       ``..``               .hhhhhhh-               ```.``");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  hhhhhhhs              shhhhhh+       -sssssss   `:osyyy`       .:+syyyyyyyys+-`       +ssssss/         `sssssss-      `:+syyyyyyyo/.             `:+syyyyyyyys+:.             .:+syyyyyyyys+-`          .hhhhhhh-          `-+syyyyyyyys+:`");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs              `......`       -hhhhhhh``+yhhhhhh.     .oyhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy:      :hhhhhhy         -hhhhhhh`    `+yhhhhhhhhhhhhyo`         `+yhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy+`         .ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy:         .hhhhhhh-        `/yhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy+`");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs                             -hhhhhhh:yhhhhhhhh.    -yhhhhhhysooshhhhhhh/      yhhhhhh-        ohhhhhh+    `shhhhhhysooshhhhhy.       `shhhhhhysoosyhhhhhhs`       :hhhhhhhysosyhhhhhhh+        .hhhhhhh-       `shhhhhhysoosyhhhhhho");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs                             -hhhhhhhhhhyssossy`   `yhhhhhh/`   `.yhhhhhh.     /hhhhhho       `hhhhhhh.    +hhhhhh/`   `-yhhhhy`      ohhhhhho.    `+hhhhhh:      .hhhhhhh:`   `:hhhhhhh-       .hhhhhhh-       ohhhhhho.    `ohhhhhh/");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs                             -hhhhhhhho-`    ``    /hhhhhhs       :hhhhhh+     `yhhhhhh`      :hhhhhho     yhhhhhy       .hhhhh:     .hhhhhhh`      `hhhhhhs      ohhhhhh+       ohhhhhho       .hhhhhhh-      .hhhhhhh`      `hhhhhhy");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs                             -hhhhhhh:             shhhhhh/       .hhhhhhy      /hhhhhh:      ohhhhhh.     yhhhhhy`       +yso/.     :hhhhhhy        shhhhhh      yhhhhhh-       /hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      /hhhhhhs        yhhhhhh.");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs       `++++++++++++++       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh:       `hhhhhhh`     `hhhhhhs     `hhhhhhs      +hhhhhhy:`     ``         +hhhhhhs        shhhhhh      ///++++.       :hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhho        shhhhhh:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs       .hhhhhhhhhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh:       `hhhhhhh`      +hhhhhh`    :hhhhhh-      `ohhhhhhhs:`              ohhhhhhs        ://////                    `/hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhho        shhhhhh/");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs       .hhhhhhhhhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhhsoooooooohhhhhhh.      `hhhhhh/    shhhhhy        `/yhhhhhhhy/`            ohhhhhhs                              `.:+syhhhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhhyoooooooohhhhhhh/");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs        ......-hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.       ohhhhhs   `hhhhhh/          .+yhhhhhhhy+.          ohhhhhhs                           .:oyhhhhhhhhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs              `hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh+:::::::::::::::`       .hhhhhh.  /hhhhhy`            `/shhhhhhhy+.        ohhhhhhs                        `:ohhhhhhyo:/hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhhs:::::::::::::::.");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println(" `hhhhhhhs              `hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh:                        ohhhhh+  shhhhh+               `-shhhhhhhh/`      ohhhhhhs                       :yhhhhhho-`  :hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhho");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  hhhhhhhs              .hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh:                        -hhhhhy `hhhhhh`                  .+yhhhhhhs`     ohhhhhhs        .......       +hhhhhho.     :hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhho");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  yhhhhhhy              -hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             hhhhhhh:       `+++++++`         shhhhh-/hhhhho                     .+hhhhhhs     ohhhhhhs        shhhhhh      /hhhhhho       :hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      ohhhhhho        /++++++-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  +hhhhhhh.             +hhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             yhhhhhh:       `hhhhhhh`         -hhhhh+shhhhh.        `.:/os:        /hhhhhh:    +hhhhhhs        shhhhhh     `hhhhhhh-       :hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      +hhhhhho        shhhhhh:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("  .hhhhhhho            -hhhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             ohhhhhh/       .hhhhhhy           shhhhhhhhhhs         ohhhhhy`        hhhhhh/    -hhhhhhy        yhhhhhy     .hhhhhhh-       /hhhhhhh       .hhhhhhh-      -hhhhhhs        yhhhhhh-");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("   /hhhhhhho.        `:yhhhhhhhh       -hhhhhhh`             -hhhhhhy`      /hhhhhh+           :hhhhhhhhhh-         :hhhhhh+`      `hhhhhh:    `yhhhhhh-      .hhhhhh+     .hhhhhhhs`    .+hhhhhhhh`      .hhhhhhh-      `yhhhhhh-      .hhhhhhy");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("    ohhhhhhhhs+/:://oyhhhyohhhhh       -hhhhhhh`              ohhhhhhs:.``-+hhhhhhy`            yhhhhhhhhs           +hhhhhhs:.``.:yhhhhhs      :hhhhhhh/.``.:yhhhhhh.      shhhhhhhyo++shhyhhhhhhh`      .hhhhhhh-       :hhhhhhy/.``.:yhhhhhh:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("     :yhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhs.:hhhhh       -hhhhhhh`              `ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy.             /hhhhhhhh:            /hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhs`       /hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh:       `shhhhhhhhhhhhs`shhhhhh-      .hhhhhhh-        /hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("      `/shhhhhhhhhhhhhy:  `hhhhh       -hhhhhhh`                -oyhhhhhhhhhhhhy/`              `hhhhhhhy              .+yhhhhhhhhhhhys:          .oyhhhhhhhhhhhhy+.         `/yhhhhhhhhy/` /hhhhhh/      .hhhhhhh-         .+yhhhhhhhhhhhhy+.");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("         `-/+ooosoo+:.     :::::       `:::::::                   `-:/+oooo+/:.                  +hhhhhh/                 .:/+ooo++:-`              `-:/+oooo+/:-`             `-/+oo+/-`   `::::::.      `:::::::`            .:/+oooo+/:-`");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("                                                                                                 +hhhhhh`");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("                                                                                          -://++shhhhhh:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("                                                                                          ohhhhhhhhhhy:");
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("                                                                                          ohhhhhhhyo:");                                                                                                                                                
        pause(.3);
        System.out.println("                                                                                          -//::-.`");            

        pause(5);

        System.out.println("\nyou begin as a man named Mason Grey, you are 30 years old, you went to college to learn how to become a detective, your parents are paying for your house, you were just fired from your job at the Police Station 1 month ago, and you have a girlfriend named Beth.");

        pause(7);

        System.out.println("\nyou arouse inside of a moving taxi");

        pause(1);

        System.out.println("\nwhat do you do?");

        pause(1.2);

        System.out.println("\nOption 1: Check your cellphone in your back pocket");

        pause(1.2);

        System.out.println("\nOption 2: Ask where you are");

        String A1 = scanny.nextLine();

        String B1 = scanny.nextLine();

        if (A1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 1") )
        {
            System.out.println("\nSuper long script");
        } else if (B1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 2") )
        {
            System.out.println("\nSecond super long script");
        }

        public static void pause(double secondsToPause) // **THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS, ON THE PUBLIC**
        {
        try
        {
            // type casting the resurt of the double times a long back into a long
            Thread.sleep((long)(1000*secondsToPause));
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```````

Comment: Is that the complete file?

Comment: Post the error and complete code.

Comment: No, it's not I, assigned all of the variables and everything and imported the scanner but I can put in the whole file.

Comment: Just posted the whole file the error is the public in the public static void pause string thing.

Comment: @Lamb move your `pause` method outside of your `main` method. Change `equalsIgnoredCase()` to `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: where would I move the pause method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket for the function definition of main.

Instead of this:

```
    if (A1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 1") )
    {
        System.out.println("\nSuper long script");
    } else if (B1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 2") )
    {
        System.out.println("\nSecond super long script");
    }

    public static void pause(double secondsToPause) // **THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS, ON THE PUBLIC**
```

This:

```
    if (A1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 1") )
    {
        System.out.println("\nSuper long script");
    } else if (B1.equalsIgnoredCase ("Option 2") )
    {
        System.out.println("\nSecond super long script");
    }
}  // <== YOU ARE MISSING THIS

public static void pause(double secondsToPause) // **THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS, ON THE PUBLIC**
```

Comment: Also, `equalsIgnoredCase` should be `equalsIgnoreCase`